# Angular innerHTML not working this string text

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-sanitizer

I'm facing an issue I'm getting an string

```
const str = '<p>Please ensure Process Model diagram represents Functions adequately (boxes that represent an activity or group of activities that produce an outcome):</p><p><br></p><p><a href="https://www.google.com" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">Click here</a></p>'
```

```
<div [innerHTML]="str"></div>
```

I want to remove this paragraph and other HTML constructs, tried using `innerHTML` but its not stripping HTML elements, not sure why. How can we remove html elements and display text and link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `DomSanitizer`.

```
public str = this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml('<p>Please ensure Process Model diagram represents Functions adequately (boxes that represent an activity or group of activities that produce an outcome):</p><p><br></p><p><a href="https://www.google.com" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">Click here</a></p>');

constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) {}
```

Comment: In addition to that, if the OP wanted to remove the outer div, they could use `outerHTML` instead of `innerHTML`.